# what is Option and [x: string] in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and very new about it. At the moment, I am trying to read some projects code so I can understand bit quicker.

I am struggling with this (I am sure it is a very basic concept), as I am a c# developer, I always try to understand the code in some kind of c# way.

```
export type NLC = string;  ---so NLC type is string
export type CRS = string;  ---so CRS type is string

export class Location {

  constructor(
    public readonly nlc: NLC,  ----we have a property nlc with type NLC (basically string)
    public readonly crs: Option<CRS>, ---what is Option, is it an optional property?
    public readonly clusters: ClusterMap, -- property with type ClusterMap
    public readonly allStations: NLC[]
  ) { }

}

**////can someone tell me what property this ClusterMap has?**
export type ClusterMap = {
  [nlc: string]: NLC; -- what is [nlc: string]?
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option

If you navigate to the definition on Option, you'll find a definition for it.

It might be a mapped type that makes all properties of the supplied type optional.

```
type Optional <T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; }
```

If so, what the code above does it for every property in the supplied type `T`, it adds the `?` annotation to make it an optional property.

When you navigate to definition on it, it could well be something else. So let me know if you need that something else explained - it could just be a simple generic interface...

```
interface Option<T> {
    myProp: string;
    obj: T
}
```

## ClusterMap

Clustermap is like a dictionary where the key (`nlc`) is a string, and the value is an `NLC`.

Example:

```
const someNlcObject = '';

const cm: ClusterMap = {
    'someKey': someNlcObject,
    'anotherKey': someNlcObject
};

cm['myKeyHere'] = someNlcObject;
cm.anyKeyYouLike = someNlcObject;

const example = cm.someKey;

const example2 = cm['myKeyHere'];
```